# Android onTouch and coordinates

Tags: android, onclick, coordinates, touch-event

I have this XML wherein I have a Relative layout and a button

[image]

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/triggerButton"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:keepScreenOn="false" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_Touch"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:elevation="2dp">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Also, I have this code to get the coordinates of the onClick and a code to get the coordinates of the button.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                point.x = event.getX();
                point.y = event.getY();
                String message = point.x + " " + point.y      

                int[] test = new int[2];
                btTrigger.getLocationOnScreen(test);

                String message2 = "X: " + test[0] + "," + "Y: " + test[1];
                Log.e("COORDINATE", message);
                Log.e("BUTTON COORDINATE", message2);

        }
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }
```

How can I check if I clicked the position of the button, without clicking the button itself. (which I can't click because the RelativeLayout is infront of the button.)

It needs to be in front of the button because whenever the user clicks the relativelayout will have a red circle.

```
canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 100, paint);
```

I have 2 options in my mind, tho idk if it's possible:

1. Increase the size of the click to adjust to the button size?
2. Or try to merge(?) the button and the relativelayout. (Whenever i click the button the drawing of circle will still appear.

Comment: If ever this helps, I need to check whether the user tapped the correct position on the relativelayout. Please help, thank you!

Comment: Also, if ever I can click the button while clicking on the Relativelayout (wherein the button is located). This would be perfect!

Comment: what purpose does the button serve if you can not see it anyway?

Comment: It's for me to ccheck if the user clicked on the correct position.